# Runtime error '13' type mismatch

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a macro to download attachments form the outlook whenever we receive a new mail, but I am getting error as "Run time Error '13' Type mismatch " and below is the code am using.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim onamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set onamespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim myfol As Outlook.Folder
Set myfol = onamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Set omail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment

For Each omail In myfol.Items

 If omail.SenderEmailAddress = "sacchu693@gmail.com" Then

  For Each Atmt In omail.Attachments

           Atmt.SaveAsFile "Z:\True_ID\46 RSA\" & Atmt.FileName

        Next
        Else
        End If


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type Mismatch in mailitem loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372849/type-mismatch-in-mailitem-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make much sense - you are creating a new message (oMail), but you never do anything with it. You just use the variable declaration to loop over *all* items in the Inbox. Since it is declared as `MailItem`, it blows up when it encounters an item of a type other than MailItem (such as `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem`).

Use `NewMailEx` event instead - it passes the new message's entry id as the parameter. Use it to call `Namespace.GetItemFromID`.